# Download google bigquery data in csv

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a requirement to download the data from google bigquery. As of now, I am hitting the google bigquery service and putting that data into dataframe and converting into csv file.The real issue coming after converting it into csv,after converting into csv the data is turned into nested form but when I am hitting the same query in bigwuery web ui. I am getting the segregated data.

I tried the above thing using pandas gbq.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('json.key')

def query_to_dataframe(query):
    return pd.read_gbq(query,
                     project_id=project_id,
                     credentials=credentials,
                     dialect='standard')

query = """
SELECT visitorId,
visitNumber,
visitId,
visitStartTime,
date,
totals.visits,
totals.hits,
totals.pageviews,
totals.timeOnSite,
totals.bounces,
totals.transactions,
totals.transactionRevenue,
totals.newVisits,
totals.screenviews,
totals.uniqueScreenviews,
totals.timeOnScreen,
totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
totals.sessionQualityDim,
trafficSource.referralPath,
trafficSource.campaign,
trafficSource.source,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.keyword,
trafficSource.adContent,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adGroupId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.creativeId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.slot,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaParameters,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.customerId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adNetworkType,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria.boomUserlistId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.isVideoAd,
trafficSource.isTrueDirect,
trafficSource.campaignCode,
device.browser,
device.browserVersion,
device.browserSize,
device.operatingSystem,
device.operatingSystemVersion,
device.isMobile,
device.mobileDeviceBranding,
device.mobileDeviceModel,
device.mobileInputSelector,
device.mobileDeviceInfo,
device.mobileDeviceMarketingName,
device.flashVersion,
device.javaEnabled,
device.language,
device.screenColors,
device.screenResolution,
device.deviceCategory,
geoNetwork.continent,
geoNetwork.subContinent,
geoNetwork.country,
geoNetwork.region,
geoNetwork.metro,
geoNetwork.city,
geoNetwork.cityId,
geoNetwork.networkDomain,
geoNetwork.latitude,
geoNetwork.longitude,
geoNetwork.networkLocation,
cd.index,
cd.value,
h.hitNumber,
h.time,
h.hour,
h.minute,
h.isSecure,
h.isInteraction,
h.isEntrance,
h.isExit,
h.referer,
h.page.pagePath,
h.page.hostname,
h.page.pageTitle,
h.page.searchKeyword,
h.page.searchCategory,
h.page.pagePathLevel1,
h.page.pagePathLevel2,
h.page.pagePathLevel3,
h.page.pagePathLevel4,
h.transaction.transactionId,
h.transaction.transactionRevenue as tRevenue,
h.transaction.transactionTax,
h.transaction.transactionShipping,
h.transaction.affiliation,
h.transaction.currencyCode,
h.transaction.localTransactionRevenue,
h.transaction.localTransactionTax,
h.transaction.localTransactionShipping,
h.transaction.transactionCoupon,
h.item.transactionId as tId,
h.item.productName,
h.item.productCategory,
h.item.productSku,
h.item.itemQuantity,
h.item.itemRevenue,
h.item.currencyCode as cCode,
h.item.localItemRevenue,
h.contentInfo.contentDescription,
h.appInfo.name,
h.appInfo.version,
h.appInfo.id,
h.appInfo.installerId,
h.appInfo.appInstallerId,
h.appInfo.appName,
h.appInfo.appVersion,
h.appInfo.appId,
h.appInfo.screenName,
h.appInfo.landingScreenName,
h.appInfo.exitScreenName,
h.appInfo.screenDepth,
h.exceptionInfo.description,
h.exceptionInfo.isFatal,
h.exceptionInfo.exceptions,
h.exceptionInfo.fatalExceptions,
h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
h.eventInfo.eventAction,
h.eventInfo.eventLabel,
h.eventInfo.eventValue,
hp.productSKU as pSKU,
hp.v2ProductName,
hp.v2ProductCategory,
hp.productVariant,
hp.productBrand,
hp.productRevenue,
hp.localProductRevenue,
hp.productPrice,
hp.localProductPrice,
hp.productQuantity,
hp.productRefundAmount,
hp.localProductRefundAmount,
hp.isImpression,
hp.isClick,
hpc.index as hpcIndex,
hpc.value as hpcValue,
hpCustomMetrics.index as cusomMetricsIndex,
hpCustomMetrics.value as cusomMetricsValue,
hp.productListName,
hp.productListPosition,
hp.productCouponCode,
hpromotion.promoId, 
hpromotion.promoName,
hpromotion.promoCreative,
hpromotion.promoPosition,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick,
h.refund.refundAmount,
h.refund.localRefundAmount,
h.eCommerceAction.action_type,
h.eCommerceAction.step,
h.eCommerceAction.option,
hExperiment.experimentId,
hExperiment.experimentVariant,
h.publisher.dfpClicks,
h.publisher.dfpImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpQueries,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.dfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxClicks,
h.publisher.adxImpressions,
h.publisher.adxMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxQueries,
h.publisher.adxRevenue,
h.publisher.adxViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsMatched,
h.publisher.viewableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.measurableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.adsPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsClicked,
h.publisher.adsRevenue,
h.publisher.dfpAdGroup,
h.publisher.dfpAdUnits,
h.publisher.dfpNetworkId,
hcustomVariables.index as hcustomVariableIndex,
hcustomVariables.customVarName,
hcustomVariables.customVarValue,
hcustomDimensions.index as customDimensionsIndex,
hcustomDimensions.value as customDimensionsvalue,
hcustomMetrics.index as hcustoMetricsIndex,
hcustomMetrics.value as hcustomMetricsValue,
h.type,
h.social.socialInteractionNetwork,
h.social.socialInteractionAction,
h.social.socialInteractions,
h.social.socialInteractionTarget,
h.social.socialNetwork,
h.social.uniqueSocialInteractions,
h.social.hasSocialSourceReferral,
h.social.socialInteractionNetworkAction,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadSample,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime,
h.latencyTracking.pageDownloadTime,
h.latencyTracking.redirectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.speedMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domainLookupTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime,
h.latencyTracking.domLatencyMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime,
h.latencyTracking.domContentLoadedTime,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingValue,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingSample,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingVariable,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingCategory,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingLabel,
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName,   
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews5,
h.dataSource,
hpublisher.dfpClicks as hpublisherDfpclicks,
hpublisher.dfpImpressions as hpublisherDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpQueries as hpublisherDfpQueries,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.dfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpPagesViewed as hpublisherDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxClicks as hpublisherAdxClicks,
hpublisher.adxImpressions as hpublisherAdxImpressions,
hpublisher.adxMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxQueries as hpublisherAdxQueries,
hpublisher.adxRevenue as hpublisherAdxRevenue,
hpublisher.adxViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsViewed as hpublisherAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsViewed as hpublisherAdsUnitsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsMatched as hpublisherAdsUnitsMatched,
hpublisher.viewableAdsViewed as hpublisherViewableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.measurableAdsViewed as hpublisherMeasurableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsClicked as hpublisherAdsClicked,
hpublisher.adsRevenue as hpublisherAdsRevenue,
hpublisher.dfpAdGroup as hpublisherDfpAdGroup,
hpublisher.dfpAdUnits as hpublisherDfpAdUnits,
hpublisher.dfpNetworkId as hpublisherDfpNetworkId,
fullVisitorId,
userId,
clientId,
channelGrouping,
socialEngagementType


FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as h
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) as hp
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.experiment) as hExperiment
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customVariables) as hcustomVariables
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcustomDimensions
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customMetrics) as hcustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher

LIMIT 100
"""

df = query_to_dataframe(query)
print(type(df))
df.to_csv("D:/PySpark/sample.csv",index=False)
```

as of now using above procedure, I am getting nested columns for many REPEATED and RECORD columns. I want to put the REPEATED columns value in different columns and same for RECORD columns. Please let me know if it is possible to achieve by using above approach or is there any other good approach to download the all data without losing the details.

Comment: BigQuery does not support CSV for your format. You will need to flatten the data in your own code. Think thru what your are trying to do. How will you handle repeated record columns? CSV is not a good format for this use case.

Comment: @John, I have to put my data into tables that's why I was going with csv format. Please let me know is there any other approach that I can try. so that I can put my data into tables after flattening.